# query not retrieving values returned from split string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I generate comma seperated string and add single quite to each numbers

Here is how i do it

```
DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(max) 

SELECT @IDs = COALESCE(@IDs +',', '') + '''' 
              + Cast([mynos] AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '''' 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  id = 22
```

If i print variable `@IDs` then i get below output

```
'78888','3333','1222'
```

When i use same variable in this query then query doesnt return any value

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  ids IN ( @IDs )
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What is the data type of ID in the table? You should look at user defined table parameters instead of these hacks.

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  You would either have to go full dynamic SQL or use a JOIN or a sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below and it worked

```
select * from table1 where id in (select mynos from mytable where id = 22)
```

Thanks to @Larnu for giving me idea

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work as your query is effectively doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Ids IN ('''78888'',''3333',''1222''');
```

Which would also be equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Ids = '''78888'',''3333',''1222''';
```

If you want to do the query as you have done, you'll need to split your delomited data out again. As you're using SQL Server 2012, you can't make use of `STRING_SPLIT`, so you'll need to a different one; such as Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE IDs IN (SELECT items
              FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K (@IDs,','));
```

However, why are you not simply doing...

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM myTable mT
              WHERE mT.Id = 22
                AND mT.myNos = T.Ids);
```

Comment: Good answer! BTW, I'd suggest you use `JOIN ` in it rather than using a nested query. It will improve the performance of the query.

Comment: Just moving ther EXISTS to a `JOIN` would actually lower speed, as the OP currently has `SELECT *`; this would mean that all the relevant rows and columns in `myTable` would need to be read too (as their values would be returned). You could, however, change the `SELECT` to `SELECT T.*`. Without actual sample data and DDL though, there's no way to know if `JOIN` or `EXISTS` will perform better.

Comment: I finally used like select * from table1 where id in (select mynos from mytable where id = 22)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic query `@id` is string variable not multi-value argument

```
DECLARE @IDs nVARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @IDs = COALESCE(@IDs +',' ,'') + '''' + CAST([myNos] AS nVARCHAR(255)) + ''''
FROM myTable WHERE Id = 22
DECLARE @query nVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @query = "Select * from table1 where Ids in ("+@IDs+")"
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Try now That because I haven't defined `@query` variable @Happy